# ⌘ + ⇧ + / not available as keyboard shortcut for 'toggle block comment'

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Since <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> is the shortcut for toggling line-comments, I wanted to set  <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> as the shortcut for toggling block-comments. If I try to put this as the shortcut in the shortcut editor, the help menu pops up instead of letting me type the combination.

I have searched if this combination is already being used anywhere else, but couldn't find any.

Now how do I set <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> as the keyboard shortcut for toggling block-comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is global macOS system shortcut. You will need to disable or change it.

*System Preference > Keyboard > App Shortcuts > Show Help menu*

I'm on macOS 10.14 Mojave, it's possible that the location of this setting might have slightly changed.